# Adding multiple canvas's to a Canvas Texture

Tags: three.js

This question is somewhat related to this [one][1]. What I'm trying to achieve is a way of allowing the user to add multiple text layers and image layers to a single mesh.

I'm creating each text/image as its own layer built using its own canvas, like this:

```
getTextCanvas(textLayer) {
    var textPositions, textXPos, textYPos, styleToAdd = '';
    if(textLayer.bold) {
      styleToAdd += ' bold ';
    }
    if(textLayer.italic) {
      styleToAdd += ' italic '
    }
    var textCanvas = this.getCanvasTextureObject(textLayer.guid, 512, 512);
    textCanvas.canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

    var ctx = textCanvas.ctx;
    ctx.font = styleToAdd + " 12px arial";

    var txtWidth = ctx.measureText(textLayer.text).width;   
    textXPos = (textCanvas.canvas.width / 2) - (txtWidth / 2);
    textYPos = textCanvas.canvas.height / 2;
    ctx.fillText(textLayer.text, textXPos, textYPos);

    return textCanvas.canvas;
}
```

The `getCanvasTextureObject()` looks like this:

```
getCanvasTextureObject(id, width?, height?) {
    var canvasEle = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvasEle.id = id;
    // When painted on the bag this style isn't honoured
    canvasEle['style'].backgroundColor = 'red';
    var ctx = canvasEle.getContext('2d');
    var texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvasEle);

    return { 
      canvas: canvasEle,
      ctx: ctx,
      texture: texture
    }
}
```

And finally I add it all to the mesh from a canvas texture mapped to a Mesh Phong Material (I think this is the wrong material though...perhaps Shader?):

```
updateBag() {

        if(!this.mainCanvas) {
          this.mainCanvas = this.getCanvasTextureObject('main-canvas', 1024, 1024);
        }
        _.forEach(this.layers, (l) => { 
            this.mainCanvas.ctx.drawImage(l.canvas, 0, 0); 
        });

        var canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(this.mainCanvas.canvas);
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x00ff00, map: canvasTexture, transparent: true, overdraw: false, opacity: 1, depthTest: false });
        this.selectedProduct[0]['children'][0].material.materials[1] = material;

    }
```

A couple of problems that I'm having are:

- Added styling set in an individual layer isn't being honoured (e.g. background-color) on the main canvas. Nor is setting the styling on the main canvas.
- I need the ability to change the ordering of the layers after they have been added. I've tried setting the **globalCompositeOperation** property on each canvas but that doesn't seem to work and have tried the same on the main canvas.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Style attributes won't affect the texture pulled from a canvas. Only the image drawn on the canvas will become the texture. So if you want a background color, you should ensure the first thing you draw to the canvas is a rectangle of that color. 2) So you're trying to apply multiple canvas textures in an arbitrary order? Yes, you could write your own texture blending into a shader, or you could re-generate the texture each time you change a layer, by re-rendering all layers to a single canvas.

Comment: @TheJim01 Could you possibly give me an example of what you mean for 2)?

Comment: Say you have 7 "layers," and each one is on a different canvas. You'll have a temporary canvas for which you obtain a 2D context. You can then draw each layer to the temporary canvas--in whatever order you want--to produce a single final texture. If you rearrange the layers, simply re-draw them to the temporary canvas in the new order, and use the temporary canvas's new image to replace the texture of your object.

Comment: @TheJim01 Sorry for late reply I'm going to apply what you're talking about now - will report back soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TheJim01 for putting me on the right path. The key, as described above was to ensure that each side is unique and added to one texture.

For me I wanted the option of adding either text or an image to any side of my object and not have them overwrite each other. First - each side of the object is an array. In that array we can have many objects, each one represents either a text or an image layer:

```
layers = {
        front: [],
        back: [],
        left: [],
        right: [],
        base: [],
        top: []
    };
```

Then when any of these arrays are modified I would redraw that side of the object by creating a canvas, assigning that canvas to a `Texture` and ensuring that each drawn image is the same size (if not then the text or the image will appear pixelated):

```
    updateBag() {
        if(this.selectedProduct) {
            var mainCanvas, canvasTexture;
            var sidesModified = this.getSidesModified();
            var side, sides = _.keys(sidesModified);

            for(var i = 0; i < sides.length; i++) {
                side = sides[i];
                mainCanvas = this.getCanvas('main-canvas', 'main');
                canvasTexture = new THREE.Texture(mainCanvas.canvas);

                for(var j = 0; j < this.layers[side].length; j++) { 
                    if(side === 'front' || side === 'back'){
                        canvasTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                      canvasTexture.repeat.x = -1;
                    }
                    mainCanvas.ctx.drawImage( this.layers[side][j].canvas, 0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);
                }
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: canvasTexture, side: THREE.FrontSide, transparent: false});
                this.setMaterialToBag(material, side);
                canvasTexture.needsUpdate = true;
            }
        }
    }
```